# Custom Thumbnails in Wordpress using Imagick

Tags: wordpress, upload, customization, thumbnails, imagick

I  want to upload an image to Wordpress and create a really custom additional thumbnail for it using imagick.

I have the code for imagick - that works. But I have no idea, how I should implement it in the wordpress upload. Can you help me with this? Is there maybe a better way to do this than to hook into the Wordpress upload event?

Thank you.

My code for imagick is:

```
    <?php
/* Create new object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* Create new checkerboard pattern */
$im->readImage('test.jpg'); 

/* Set the image format to png */
$im->setImageFormat('png');

/* Fill new visible areas with transparent */
$im->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

/* Activate matte */
$im->setImageMatte(true);

/* Control points for the distortion */
$controlPoints = array(500, 30, 133,150,90,2800);
/*size, inner-circle, padding links, padding-top (jeweils Mittelpunkt), wie weit, */


/* Perform the distortion */                       
$im->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_POLAR, $controlPoints, true);



/* Ouput the image */
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have ImageMagick enabled but you don’t have the Imagick PHP extension. Without both WordPress won’t automatically use ImageMagick. This plugin enables you to use it and has other awesome features.

You can use follwing plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagemagick-engine/